# NVIDIA vs PyTorch versions of cuDNN

Tags: pytorch, cudnn

After installing PyTorch as per the official command:
`conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`, my cuDNN version shown in `conda list` is `pytorch 1.7.1 py3.8_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0 pytorch` whereas my system has `cudnn8.5.0`.

Does it have an affect on how we train models?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**; Probably no, but depends on the difference between versions.

### Explanation

In reality upgrades (like what you have conda `cudnn7.6.5_0` -> `cudnn8.5.0` of the system) usually don't harm training because versions are backward compatible for a while. After a while, things get deprecated though (years probably), so you should try to not totally make this absurdly large, such that CUDA version uses operations that aren't implemented. You should be more interested in which minimal version is required from your GPU (like 3090's from Nvidia which requires CUDA 11.1 and above).

In reality, torch uses simple operation implementation of cudnn, and usually, they don't change that much. As [Nvidia describes what cuDNN is](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn):

> The NVIDIA CUDA® Deep Neural Network library (cuDNN) is a GPU-accelerated library of primitives for deep neural networks. cuDNN provides highly tuned implementations for standard routines such as forward and backward convolution, pooling, normalization, and activation layers.

If you are interested to check the actual matrix support from Nvidia, [check this website documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/archives/index.html) and click on the version support matrix of a specific version. You can see that `cuDNN 8.5.0 for CUDA 10.2` is supported by 8.5.0. If you think what `py3.8_cuda10.2.89_cudnn7.6.5_0` means, it is saying that your `cuda10.2.89` was compiled with the primitives available in `cudnn7.6.5`.
Also, consider that you also have to have the [required version of Nvidia driver](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/#minor-version-compatibility).